# Best practice for predicting values from model with Chainer

Tags: chainer

With [Chainer](http://chainer.org/), I have created `model.pkl` with *Iris Datasets* (https://github.com/silwyb/train-iris). So I can evaluate datasets, but I don't know the best way to output predicted values.

Please tell me how to predict. Just a function name would also be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The following works.
[silwyb/train-iris/predict.py](https://github.com/silwyb/train-iris/blob/master/predict.py)

```
def predict(x_test):
    x = Variable(x_test)

    h1 = F.dropout(F.relu(model.l1(x)))
    h2 = F.dropout(F.relu(model.l2(h1)))
    y = model.l3(h2)

    return np.argmax(y.data)
```